# JTable: How to render Boolean as Color, and edit as text using JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render

I tried to make Boolean renderer and Boolean editor.

The Boolean renderer should render Boolean values as colors (two colors).
The Boolean Editor should return a JTextField and enable editing as String "T" and "F"

So if you click the cell and type "T" or "F" the color of the cell must be shifted to the corresponding color.

Based on [this oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) I tried to make my renderer and editor and include it with [this oracle provided example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TableDialogEditDemo).

Below Boolean renderer and Boolean editor. I registered them to [this class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/TableDialogEditDemo.java).

```
        ....
        ....

        table.setDefaultRenderer(Color.class,
                new ColorRenderer(true));
        table.setDefaultEditor(Color.class,
                new ColorEditor());


        table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new BooleanRenderer()); // My
        table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class, new BooleanEditor());     // My

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
        ....
        ....
```

The cells aren't rendered at all, and things doesn't work as expected!.

**What is the wrong with my code?**

My Renderer:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class BooleanRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        if (hasFocus)
        {
            Boolean bol = (Boolean) value;
            if (bol == Boolean.FALSE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.red);
                this.setText("");
            } else if (bol == Boolean.TRUE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Boolean bol = (Boolean) value;
            if (bol == Boolean.FALSE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.red);
                this.setText("");
            } else if (bol == Boolean.TRUE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }

        if (isSelected)
        {
            Boolean bol = (Boolean) value;
            if (bol == Boolean.FALSE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.red);
                this.setText("");
            } else if (bol == Boolean.TRUE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        } else
        {
            Boolean bol = (Boolean) value;
            if (bol == Boolean.FALSE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.red);
                this.setText("");
            } else if (bol == Boolean.TRUE)
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }


        return this;
    }
}
```

My Editor:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;


public class BooleanEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
        implements TableCellEditor
{

    Boolean bool;
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return bool;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {


        if (isSelected)
        {
            bool = (Boolean) value;
            if (tf.getText().equals("T"))
            {
                bool = new Boolean(true);
            } else
            {
                if (tf.getText().equals("F"))
                {
                    bool = new Boolean(false);
                }
            }

        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Comment: FYI, consider replacing code such as `if (bol == Boolean.FALSE)` by simply `if(!bol)`: shorter, cleaner and more readable. Moreover, `bool = new Boolean(true)` can be replaced by simply writing `bool = true` (also cleaner, simpler and more readable). Finally, instead of writing `if(tf.getText().equals("T")) bool = true; else bool = false;` simply write: `bool = tf.getText().equals("T");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For your renderer**:
you must give it a constructor and inside of the constructor, set it to opaque:

```
public BooleanRenderer() {
  setOpaque(true);
}
```

Else the JLabel won't display any background color at all.

**For your JTable cell editor:**

- First of all, I must recommend against your design since leaving it up to the user to type in the correct text, "T" or "F" is too prone to user entry errors. Better to give him a choice such as by using a JComboBox.
- Next, get rid of the `if (isSelected)` block in your editor. The editor will be called when needed, and selected will likely be false making your code non-functioning.
- Most importantly: get rid of your editor's bool field. In the `getCellEditorValue()` method, query the component for its value and return the appropriate boolean based on this value.

For example:

```
public class BooleanEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

   JComboBox<Boolean> combo = new JComboBox<Boolean>(new Boolean[] {
         Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE });

   public BooleanEditor() {
      combo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
         @Override
         public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
               Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Boolean boolValue = (Boolean) value;
            String displayString = "";
            if (boolValue == null) {
               displayString = "";
            } else if (boolValue) {
               displayString = "T";
            } else {
               displayString = "F";
            }
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, displayString,
                  index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public Object getCellEditorValue() {
      return combo.getSelectedItem();
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
         boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
      if (value == null) {
         combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
      } else {
         combo.setSelectedItem((Boolean) value);
      }
      return combo;
   }
}
```

My entire [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class BoolColorTable {
   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      // null just to test how code will react to this situation
      // that hopefully won't occur
      Boolean[][] data = { null, { true }, { false }, { true }, { false },
            { false }, { true } };
      String[] colNames = { "Data" };
      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);
      JTable table = new JTable(model) {
         @Override
         public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            if (column == 0) {
               return Boolean.class;
            }
            return super.getColumnClass(column);
         }
      };

      table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new BooleanRenderer());
      table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class, new BooleanEditor());

      JScrollPane mainPanel = new JScrollPane(table);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoolColorTable");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BooleanRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
   public BooleanRenderer() {
      setOpaque(true);
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
         boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      Boolean boolValue = (Boolean) value;
      if (boolValue == null) {
         setBackground(null);
      } else {
         if (!boolValue) {
            this.setBackground(Color.red);
         } else {
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
         }
      }
      return this;
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BooleanEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

   JComboBox<Boolean> combo = new JComboBox<Boolean>(new Boolean[] {
         Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE });

   public BooleanEditor() {
      combo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
         @Override
         public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
               Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Boolean boolValue = (Boolean) value;
            String displayString = "";
            if (boolValue == null) {
               displayString = "";
            } else if (boolValue) {
               displayString = "T";
            } else {
               displayString = "F";
            }
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, displayString,
                  index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public Object getCellEditorValue() {
      return combo.getSelectedItem();
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
         boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
      if (value == null) {
         combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
      } else {
         combo.setSelectedItem((Boolean) value);
      }
      return combo;
   }
}
```

**Edit**
If you *absolutely* need to allow the user to be able to enter "T" or "F", then you can do this and make it mostly idiot proof by adding a DocumentFilter to the editor's JTextField that will allow only three case insensitive possible text field entries: "t", "f", or empty.

For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BooleanStringEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField();

   public BooleanStringEditor() {
      PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) textField.getDocument();
      doc.setDocumentFilter(new MyDocFilter());
   }

   @Override
   public Object getCellEditorValue() {
      if (textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
         return Boolean.TRUE;
      } else if (textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
         return Boolean.FALSE;
      }
      // default if user messes up
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
         boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
      Boolean boolValue = (Boolean) value;
      if (boolValue == null) {
         textField.setText("");
      } else if (boolValue) {
         textField.setText("T");
      } else {
         textField.setText("F");
      }
      return textField;
   }

}

class MyDocFilter extends DocumentFilter {

   private boolean test(String text) {
      if (text.isEmpty()) {
         return true;
      }
      if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("t") || text.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
         AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.insert(offset, string);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
         AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }

   }

   @Override
   public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
         throws BadLocationException {
      Document doc = fb.getDocument();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
      sb.delete(offset, offset + length);

      if (test(sb.toString())) {
         super.remove(fb, offset, length);
      } else {
         // warn the user and don't allow the insert
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: @Saleh Feek use JComboBox as TableCellEditor, instead of JTextField

Comment: @Hovercraft ✓ Thank you very much for this great help. I know that JComboBox is better. But in this case I am just learning and trying to make my code work.